# How to combine result of 3 tables to calculate average marks in MySql?

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have tables like

1. Student(Rollno, Name, Address)
2. Subject(Sub_code, Sub_name)
3. Marks(Roll_no, Sub_code, Marks)

I want to write query for **average marks (for all subjects) for each student along with name of the student**

e.g. 
[image: Example Data with Expected Output]

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know [**INNER JOIN**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) and [**GROUP BY**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) ?

Answer (score 0):

You could join by the `rollno` and group the results by the student's `rollno`:

```
SELECT   s.rollno, name, AVG(marks)
FROM     student s
JOIN     marks m ON s.rollno = m.rollno
GROUP BY s.rollno, name
```

Comment: I think you want `GROUP BY rollno, name` In case two students have the same name.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza probably not a bad idea. In the given data set the name is unique, but I agree we shouldn't assume it.